# Colormapping the Mandelbrot set by iterations in python

Tags: python-3.x, mandelbrot, color-mapping

I am using np.ogrid to create the x and y grid from which I am drawing my values. I have tried a number of different ways to color the scheme according to the iterations required for |z| >= 2 but nothing seems to work. Even when iterating 10,000 times just to be sure that I have a clear picture when zooming, I cannot figure out how to color the set according to iteration ranges. Here is the code I am using, some of the structure was borrowed from a tutorial. Any suggestions?

```
#I found this function and searched in numpy for best usage for this type of density plot
x_val, y_val = np.ogrid[-2:2:2000j, -2:2:2000j]

#Creating the values to work with during the iterations
c = x_val + 1j*y_val
z = 0
iter_num = int(input("Please enter the number of iterations:"))

for n in range(iter_num):
    z = z**2 + c
    if n%10 == 0:
        print("Iterations left: ",iter_num - n)

#Creates the mask to filter out values of |z| > 2
z_mask = abs(z) < 2
proper_z_mask = z_mask - 255 #switches current black/white pallette
#Creating the figure and sizing for optimal viewing on a small laptop screen
plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,8))
plt.imshow(z_mask.T, extent=[-2, 2, -2, 2])
plt.gray()
plt.show()
```

Comment: To start with, use a gray scale from `iterations % 256` where the iterations are less than the limit and the function has escaped.